# Test Aspnet.security.openidconnect.server with client application

Tags: asp.net, oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-2.0, openid-connect

I have created a project in .net core 2.1 and implemented ASOS, Now I want to test authorization flow like I want to open login screen and then I will select my ssl certificate and will get the token so for that purpose I have created a client app but it's returning 404 on /connect/authorization endpoint.

Here is the ASOS implementations:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddOAuthValidation()
            .AddOpenIdConnectServer(options =>
            {
                options.AuthorizationEndpointPath = new PathString(AuthorizePath);
                // Enable the token endpoint.
                options.TokenEndpointPath = new PathString(TokenPath);
                options.ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true;
                options.AccessTokenLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
#if DEBUG
                 options.AllowInsecureHttp = true;
#endif
                options.Provider.OnValidateAuthorizationRequest = context =>
                {
                    if (string.Equals(context.ClientId, Configuration["OpenIdServer:ClientId"], StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        context.Validate(context.RedirectUri);
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
                // Implement OnValidateTokenRequest to support flows using the token endpoint.
                options.Provider.OnValidateTokenRequest = context =>
                {
                // Reject token requests that don't use grant_type=password or grant_type=refresh_token.
                if (!context.Request.IsClientCredentialsGrantType() && !context.Request.IsPasswordGrantType()
                    && !context.Request.IsRefreshTokenGrantType())
                    {
                        context.Reject(
                       error: OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.UnsupportedGrantType,
                       description: "Only grant_type=password and refresh_token " +
                                    "requests are accepted by this server.");

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.ClientId))
                    {
                        context.Skip();

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }

                    if (string.Equals(context.ClientId, Configuration["OpenIdServer:ClientId"], StringComparison.Ordinal) &&
                        string.Equals(context.ClientSecret, Configuration["OpenIdServer:ClientSecret"], StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        context.Validate();
                    }

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

                // Implement OnHandleTokenRequest to support token requests.
                options.Provider.OnHandleTokenRequest = context =>
                {
                 // Only handle grant_type=password token requests and let
                 // the OpenID Connect server handle the other grant types.
                 if (context.Request.IsClientCredentialsGrantType() || context.Request.IsPasswordGrantType())
                    {
                     //var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Scheme.Name,
                     //    OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name,
                     //    OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role);
                     ClaimsIdentity identity = null;
                        if (context.Request.IsClientCredentialsGrantType())
                        {
                            identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(context.Request.ClientId, "Bearer"), context.Request.GetScopes().Select(x => new Claim("urn:oauth:scope", x)));
                        }
                        else if (context.Request.IsPasswordGrantType())
                        {
                            identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(context.Request.Username, "Bearer"), context.Request.GetScopes().Select(x => new Claim("urn:oauth:scope", x)));
                        }
                     // Add the mandatory subject/user identifier claim.
                     identity.AddClaim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n") + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n"));

                     // By default, claims are not serialized in the access/identity tokens.
                     // Use the overload taking a "destinations" parameter to make sure
                     // your claims are correctly inserted in the appropriate tokens.
                     identity.AddClaim("urn:customclaim", "value",
                     OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken,
                     OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken);

                        var ticket = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationTicket(
                         new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
                         new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties(),
                         context.Scheme.Name);

                     // Call SetScopes with the list of scopes you want to grant
                     // (specify offline_access to issue a refresh token).
                     ticket.SetScopes(
                         OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile,
                         OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OfflineAccess);

                        context.Validate(ticket);
                    }

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
```

and here is the client app:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "GitHub";
                })
                .AddCookie()
                .AddOAuth("GitHub", options =>
                {
                    options.ClientId = "4trgdff3dfadffsfsa";
                    options.ClientSecret = "sds4546ddsdsdsdsds";
```

//not sure about the callback
                        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/login");

```
                    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://localhost/WebApp/connect/authorize";
                    options.TokenEndpoint = "https://localhost/WebApp/connect/token";
                    options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://localhost/WebApp/userinfo";

                    options.SaveTokens = true;

                    //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
                    //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
                    //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:login", "login");
                    //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:url", "html_url");
                    //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:avatar", "avatar_url");

                    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
                    {
                        OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                        {
                            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                            var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                            var user = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                            context.RunClaimActions(user);
                        }
                    };
                });
        }
```

Here is the controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = "/")
    {
        return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = returnUrl });
    }
```

Here is the error:

```
This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost/WebApp/connect/authorize?client_id=TWXO02aIDkK7564eoAh0wQ&scope=&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A54108%2Flogin&state=CfDJ8LygGi9uYeFEkbvAts2SZpy6ytnFjrcNCCmeVAA15dDCN7fSq4IEX2A6OUeEWOmpxrFovAciUEwUIaV9WKer23ty_RGMWQ0YewdllgE2bicTfzHcl-d9RvHGuIKmknE3_lF_o0GETgCrPcjkMvarC8CpSOQGKl88FsZg3Zpk1YXmhvS_vHBkU_hKipl27ivYzVHK1VVKIWYLmR4FSrtu7Ic
```

I found this client app implementation from this link https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/authenticate-oauth-aspnet-core-2/ Now I am not sure what is wrong, Also my app with ASOS implementation is deployed on local iis
Any help?

Comment: Perhaps you should specify the port number.

Comment: I hsd also tried that, but got same results. Second thing is my app is deployed on local iis.